Event Bubbling in Hierarchical State Machine (HSM)
Assume the following setup

We are in state A0.
What happens if the "EVENT" event is triggered?
Technically "A0" specifies how to handle the "EVENT" event. But the guard returns 'false'.
Is the event then handled by "A" or are we stuck in "A0"?
